# Why it is legal to compare scoped enumerations

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

Although scoped enumerations (`enum class`) cannot be implicitly converted to integral types, I still can compare them by `<` (on GCC 10.3).

```cpp
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

enum class Colours {
    Red = 0,
    Green = 1,
    Blue = 2
};

int main() {
    std::cout << (std::min(Colours::Blue, Colours::Red) < Colours::Green) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Why is this standard behaviour (if it is)?

Could you give me a reference to [cppreference.com](http://cppreference.com) or c++ standard?

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but `Red = 0, Green = 1, Blue = 2` can be written `Red, Green, Blue`. If the first enumerator doesn't have an initializer it gets the value 0. Any other enumerator that doesn't have an initializer get the value that's one more than its predecessor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is described in [comparison operators](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_comparison)

> **Arithmetic comparison operators**
>
> If the operands have arithmetic or **enumeration type (scoped or unscoped)**, usual arithmetic conversions are performed on both operands following the rules for arithmetic operators. The values are compared after conversions:

So in addition to arithmetic types (including integral types), scoped and unscoped enum types are explicitly mentioned.